# How to use a special shell variable in If then statements

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm fairly new to scripting and I want to learn how to check the values of `$?` to check whether the a grep command was successful, **If** the grep command is **not successful**, **then** to echo a message which includes the values of **$name**.
  How can I achieve this, I'm aware that I can use an If statement and a special shell variable but I don't know the proper syntax. I gave it a try in the code below.

```
name=$1
         if [ "$name" =  "" ]
         then  echo -n "Name 'DBS' is not in directory"
            read name
         fi

grep -i $name mike ~admin/dbs/email
grep -i goodman ~admin/dbs/passwd
```

Comment: show an example of what you're trying to do with grep.  from what you've shown so far, grep is irrelevant.

Comment: I updated the script @cas

Comment: Re: your edit adding the `grep -i ...` examples. I am confused, as the first command looks for the pattern in `$name` in the files `mike` and `~admin/dbs/email`, then the second one looks for `goodman`, so I'm thinking the first line probably doesn't do what you want it to. Can you elaborate on exactly what you're trying to search with those `grep` statements? And then, which `grep` statement are you interested in the status (`$?`) of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some fairly typical syntax. It could do with some more error checking, but within the scope of what you're looking to do, I believe this will help you on to the right track:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/etc/hosts

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo Usage: $0 name 1>&2
    exit 2
fi

if grep -q "$1" $file ; then
    echo "$file" contains $1
else
    echo "$file" doesn\'t contain $1
fi
```

### Notes

- The first `test` (`if [ -z "$1" ]; then ...`) is true if `$1` (first commandline argument) is an empty string (or was not provided).
- The `Usage:` line is output to `stderr` with `1>&2`
- The output of `grep` itself is hidden (except for error output, which you'd probably want to see), since in this case we only want to know if it was successful (match found) or not.

  - `grep` has a parameter `-q` that silences all output, which is the better choice here, but not all commands have a "quiet" switch, In those cases, you can use `>/dev/null` instead, as in my example below.

### Specific example with `$?`

You specifically asked for an example with `$?`. Instead of the above `if grep ...` construct, we could indeed split that into separate statements:

```
# grep -q "$1" $file would work just as well, here (better, maybe!):
grep "$1" $file >/dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$file" contains $1
else
    echo "$file" doesn\'t contain $1
fi
```

It's important to note that testing `$?` must happen immediately after the command in question, as any other commands (excluding some shell builtins) will cause the value to be overwritten.

### What is `$?`

`$?` is simply the exit code of the last process (command) executed by the shell. By convention, a `0` exit code is success (although, as with most conventions, there are exceptions). Higher exit codes can have various meanings specific to the application, but *usually* non-zero means some kind of abnormal exit. Consult the documentation of the command for more information.

### Further reading

[test(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test)

Comment: try `grep -q` rather than `grep > /dev/null`

Comment: @cas Indeed, that would be a better practice. Initially I had thought `>/dev/null` would provide for a more general example, but I agree; no point teaching over-generalized habits when `-q` will do. I'll work it in.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way, that avoids if-statements as well as `$?`, but is pretty nice and short (oneliner!), in my opinion, would be:

```
grep -q $name $file || echo "$name not found."
```

if you want to `echo` if `grep` returns `0`:

```
grep -q $name $file && echo "$name found."
```

and as an if-else-statemet:

```
grep -q $name $file && echo "$name found." || echo "$name not found."
```